# jquery dialog: confirm the click on a submit button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a confirm dialog using jquery, but the form doesn't get submitted at all, this is what I got:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var currentForm;
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                'Delete all items': function() {
                    currentForm.submit();
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function ask() {
        currentForm = $(this).closest('form');
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
    }
</script>
<form ... >
    <input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="ask();return false;" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to have your dialog button submit the `<form>`, like this:

```
               'Delete all items': function() {
                  $(this).dialog('close');
                  $("#myForm").submit();
                }
```

The rest of your code is correct, but it's currently just closing the dialog and returning, you need to actually submit the form.  Also, it's better to do this as a click handler, instead of `onclick`, like this (**updated for comments**):

```
    var currentForm;
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                'Delete all items': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    currentForm.submit();
                },
                'Cancel': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        $(".delete").click(function() {
          currentForm = $(this).closest('form');
          $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
          return false;
        });
    });
```

Then just give your `<input>` an class of `delete`, like this:

```
<input class="delete" type="submit" value="delete" />
```

Comment: the problem is that i have lots of forms, each one with a delete button inside of it, it's just a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name='id' value='the id to be delted' />` that makes the difference between these forms

Comment: I could give the forms different names/ids, the name could contain form+theId

Comment: @Omu - You can store a "currentForm = `$(this).closest('form')` in the click function when it opens, then just call `currentForm.submit()` in the delete button's handler, no IDs needed...and just change the delete click handler to use a class or attribute selector.

Comment: @Nick Craver I tried your approach (also updated the question), the form doesn't get submitted

Comment: @Omu - I meant with the answer approach :)  What you have won't work overall.  The answer is updated to hopefully show exactly what I mean.

Comment: it works with a return false on the input, otherwise it's insta-submit

Comment: Omu - Make sure you have `return false` in the click handler like the answer does!

Comment: :) ya it does, I've added it in the answer

Comment: @Omu - Doh, my fault, didn't even see the edit, thanks for improving this for future googlers :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery, then do it properly and avoid inline Javascript:

```
$(function (){
  $("form").submit(function (){
    // return false if you don't want this to be submitted
    // maybe do a
    // return ask();
    // but with the code provided it doesn't seem
    // to work like that - ask() is not returning anything at all!
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content"
    });

    function confirmDialog(title, message, success) {
        var confirmdialog = $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
            .html('<div><h6>' + message + '</h6></div>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: title,
                zIndex: 10000,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 'auto',
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function () {
                        success();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    No: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });

        return confirmdialog.dialog("open");
    }

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;

        confirmDialog('Confirm', 'Are you sure?', function () {
            form.submit();
        });
    });
});
```

Reference:  http://jsfiddle.net/pmw57/67Ge2/

Answer (score 1):

For a form with `GET` method as I need also button's value in query string and avoid to lost it at form submit

I used `event.preventDefault()` and added button's name and value as  `hidden <input> field` in JS script

JS script

```
$( function() {
  //Add function to all document's html tag with class="delete"
  $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); //Stop submitting form and wait for a "yes" or "no"

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );

          //Prevent to lost button's value in query string at form submit
          //Need to add a hidden <input> field with the same button's name and value
          $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                        .attr('name', 'action')
                        .attr('value', 'delete')
                        .appendTo('#myform');

          $('#myform').submit(); //Ok proceed with form submit 

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" ); //Do nothing, close window.
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Form template

```
<div style="display:none" id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<form id="myform" action="#myurl" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input class="delete" type="submit" name="action" value="delete">
</form>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( function() {
      $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault(); //Stop submitting form and wait for a "yes" or "no"

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          draggable: false,
          resizable: false,
          height: "auto",
          width: 400,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Delete items": function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              
              //Prevent to lost button's value in query string at form submit
              //Need to add a hidden <input> field with the same button's name and value
              $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                            .attr('name', 'action')
                            .attr('value', 'delete')
                            .appendTo('#myform');

              $('#myform').submit(); //Ok proceed with form submit

            },
            Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" ); //Do nothing, close window.
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div style="display:none" id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<form id="myform" action="#myurl" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input class="delete" type="submit" name="action" value="delete">
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```