# JavaScript confirmation is automatically posting form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Partial View which contains a file input for uploading files(s). A User on this view will select a file from their workstation and click the upload button.  The upload click submits the form to an action method and the files are parsed and the same view is returned to auto-populate a few fields on the view.

Everything as is, is working perfectly. I am adding a new requirement to the existing view which is as following:

**Requirement**

User selects a file and clicks the upload button. Once the upload button is clicked, a JavaScript confirmation dialog is displayed to the users which contains two button options before the form is submitted to the controller action method. These buttons are "Buffer Run Parsing" and "Normal Parsing". Clicking any of these buttons will post to the controller action method.

In the controller action method upon post, My goal is to capture which button they pressed and based on the button pressed I select the file parsing logic accordingly.

**The Problem**

I created a JavaScript function which does display the two buttons but the dialog box automatically disappears and the form posts to the controller.  I would like it to not post until I click either button with the confirmation.

Here is what I am doing:

**Main View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <div id="main">
        @Html.Partial("_RunLogEntryPartialView", Model)
    </div>
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
<button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="initUploadDailog();return false;"
    style="width: 100px">
    Upload</button>

<div id="uploadConfirmation" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; overflow: scroll;
    width: 800px; height: 450px; display: none;">
</div>
```

**JS Function:**

```
 function initUploadDailog(e) {
        currentForm = $(this).closest('form');
        UploadDialog = $("#uploadConfirmation").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            autoOpen: true,
            title: 'Please select parsing type for Test Completed Computation',
            buttons: {
                "Normal Parsing": function () {
                    $("#hiddenInput").val("Normal");
                    alert(currentForm.innerHtml());
                    currentForm.submit();
                },
                "Buffer Parsing": function () {
                    $("#hiddenInput").val("Buffer Run");
                    currentForm.submit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
   [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create(RunLogEntry runLogEntry, String ServiceRequest, string Hour, string Minute, string AMPM,
                                     string submit, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file, String AssayPerformanceIssues1, List<string> Replicates)
        {
}
```

Comment: Can you try by replacing $("#hiddenInput").val("Normal"); with  $("#hiddenInput").attr("value", "Normal"). I know both are same but recently I ran into such scenario where I had to make such change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Congrats! You've hit a very obscure bug and hard to troubleshoot!**

The problem is with your markup; your button has the attribute `name="submit"`. Remove it as shown:

```html
<button class="art-button" type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="initUploadDailog();return false;" style="width: 100px">Upload</button>
```

When you call `currentForm.submit()`, it is **not** calling the native `form.submit()` function; it is **trying to use the button element as a function**!

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zarDj/) of your code.

---

A little bit of history: because of the almighty Internet Explorer, elements with the `name` attribute set are automatically turned into objects (or child objects) accessible directly through JavaScript. This was initially thought out by the IE team years ago (while not following JavaScript/EMCA standards), and because of the vast amount of legacy websites, WebKit (Chrome, Safari) and Gecko (Firefox) have implemented the same *broken* behavior.

Comment: Hi Jesse, I was not able to come online earlier, thanks for your solution. I have verified yours and it works! I ended up adding another submit button for uploading files as users were okay with. At least I learned from your solution.

Comment: Glad it helped - now you know why you can't give elements the same name as functions. =)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to do.

First, set `Modal` to true.  False means that it won't prevent the user from clicking on other things on the page besides the box.

Second, you need to change the `onclick` on the submit button to include `;return false;`  It should read `onclick=initUploadDailog();return false;"`  This will prevent the form from simply submitting once the submit button is clicked.

Third, the dialog itself needs to submit the form once the appropriate button is selected.  See here: [jquery dialog: confirm the click on a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881706/jquery-dialog-confirm-the-click-on-a-submit-button)

Comment: Thanks, I did correct my code to the changes you suggested and also in the question above.  I do get the modal open, but the button clicks, I believe are not finding the form at all so thats why it does not submit. The click event works fine though.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 solutions.  First, if you just want to use everything the way it is, try changing your `onclick="initUploadDailog();return false;"` to `onclick="return initUploadDailog();"`.  Then I think your browser will wait for a return of true or false before posting the form.

But, if you want to use jQuery the way it is intended, you're going to want to look at jQuery's [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).  First, give your button an ID like `id="art-button"`.  Next, change your function to bind to the button click (I like using .bind vs .click for browser compatibility).

Change this:

```
function initUploadDailog(e) {
    // Your code
}
```

To this:

```
$("#art-button").bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Your code
    $("#form-id").submit();
});
```

You could also bind to the actual form submit, prevent the default, and use AJAX to post your data.