# jquery modal confirm issue

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a delete input button that `$_POST`s to the same page. I have a jquery confirm modal that pops up when it is clicked. If yes then it posts the form, if no it cancels that action.

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['doDelete'] == 'Delete') {
        if (!empty($_POST['u'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
                $id = filter($uid);
                if (deleteRecord('projects', $id, false)) {
                    $fail[] = $id;
                } else {
                    $pass[] = $id;
                }
            }
        }
        $msg = new Messages();
        if (!empty($pass)) {
            $passed = implode(', ', $pass);
            $message = "Deleted: {$passed}";
            $msg->add('s', $message);
        }
        if(!empty($fail)){
            $failure = implode(', ', $fail);
            $message = "Could not delete/an error occured: {$failure}";
            $msg->add('e', $message);
        }
        redirect('projects.php');
    }
?>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 300,
            modal: true,
            show: {
                effect: "bounce",
                duration: 100
            },
            hide: "drop",
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $("#confirm").submit();
                },
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#doDelete").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<form post="self.php" id="confirm">
<!-- some inputs .etc -->
<input name="doDelete" type="submit" id="doDelete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

The button id is `doDelete`, and the forms id is `confirm`. The modal however only closes itself after the user clicks `yes` without posting the form. When I comment out this code, the button works fine, and deletes the records (the post succeeds).

Similar to: [jquery dialog: confirm the click on a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881706/jquery-dialog-confirm-the-click-on-a-submit-button)

Comment: What warning? Deleting what posts?

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your html. Where and how do you set `currentForm`?

Comment: i made it more clear. the `currentForm` is commented out. if the user clicks yes i just want to submit confirm. hence `$("#confirm").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Alex:

Try to make the ajax call as the following way:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YOUR_PHP_URL",
        data: "YOUR_VARIABLE",
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () { /// use beforeSend to open a dialog box 

        $("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog({
          //...

        });


        },
        success: function (response) {
            //the dialog will just load but the form will still continue to submit                             
        }

    });
```

The magic comes when you use the "beforeSend" function... I hope that I can help you with this...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the form before closing the dialog?

```
$("#dialog-confirm-multiple").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $("#confirm").submit();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I have, and it didn't make any difference